# Why don't put var in a parameter of a function?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I am new to Javascript and I know, that we should always put "var" before variable for safety except we want to make it global. But why we don't put "var" as a function's parameter? Here example:

```
function sum(a, b){
   return a + b;
}
not this variant:
function sum(var a, var b){
  return a + b;
}
```

Comment: because it's javascript there is no need to use var  because in js you don't declare int,string .. only var.in languages like java you should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you said is wrong.

You shouldn't always write "var".
When you do it, it's not for safety. 
Also, you can have a global, window scoped, variable, writting "var" before its name. It's where you declare it that determines its scope.

As for your question, the answer is: because that's Javascript syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I have strcucturized information in my head